# Error opening the cache(E:flAbspath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (13:permission denied) )

Tags: apt, permissions, updates, dpkg, 20.04

So I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and then I started getting this error on the top bar of my desktop:

```
Error opening the cache(E:flAbspath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (13:permission denied), 
E: could not open file - open(2: No such file or directory), 
E: Problem opening,
E: The Package list or status file could not be parsed or open). 
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Also when I use `sudo apt update` I get the warning:

> W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/mirror.de.leaseweb.net_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

I checked my status file in /var/lib/dpkg/status and here is the file :

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3192885 May 16 11:12 /var/lib/dpkg/status

I also set changed the ownership of /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ to `_apt:root` but nothing seems to **work**!